# Easiest way to get going with Zurb Foundation on an existing Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, zurb-foundation, css-frameworks

Me (developer) and my designer friend are making an app with Sinatra. Now we want to use Zurb Foundation with it (because it makes his job much easier). What's the easiest way to use that in Sinatra?

Comment: I find the documentation especially with regard to sinatra to be lacking in clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Just use http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html this steps.
First install bower and grunt-cli
Then stand alone foundation gem (not foundation-rails) and then just use foundation new [project name]. If you have existence html and css add them in foundation project folder that is all. Also yu can use http://ricostacruz.com/sinatra-assetpack/